# What is another expression for enormous amount of hard-working practice?

Tags: expressions

What is another expression for enormous amount of hard-working practice, concisely in one or two words? This is for the situation for a mechanics trying to hone their skills.

The search engine these day are not so advance for finding synonymous expression, therefore I would rather to choose to ask here.

Comment: Could you give an example of how you'd use it, to help frame a context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"**Diligence**" is one word that comes to mind:

TheFreeDictionary [defines diligence](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/diligence) as:

> 1. Earnest and persistent application to an undertaking; steady effort; assiduity.
> 2. Attentive care; heedfulness.

Of the above two definitions, the first one is closest to what you're looking for.

You could use it in a sentence like:

> The apprentice worked diligently under the lead mechanic's guidance.

Another related term is that of "**elbow grease**", but that is different in that elbow grease refers to pure physical effort only, and not honing of skills.